# 'Generating App Engine Backend' error in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/#eclb) to build an Android app with an App Engine backend.

When I right click the Android project and select Generate App Engine Backend, I get the following error: `'Generating App Engine Backend' has encountered a problem.` 
Nothing is displayed in the console.

No AppEngine project is created and there are no errors in the Android project.
I'm using Eclipse 4.2 Juno, Windows 7 x64, App Engine SDK 1.9.15, GPE 3.8.0 and Java 1.8.0_25.

I've searched for this problem and it seems like it was happening for Windows users some time ago but it was apparently fixed.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.